# Implement modInverse using Extended Euclid Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, euclidean-algorithm

modInverse method of class BigInteger should not be used. I tried and used this method but it does not produce the correct result. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static int[] extendedgcd(int a, int b) {
        if (b==0) {
            return new int[]{1, 0, a};
        } else {
            int output[] = extendedgcd(b, a%b);
            return new int[]{output[0], output[0]-((a/b)*output[1]), output[2]};
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the else-branch, the first return value should be `output[1]` instead of `output[0]`:

```
public static int[] extendedgcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return new int[]{1, 0, a};
    } else {
        int output[] = extendedgcd(b, a % b);
        return new int[]{
            output[1],
            output[0] - ((a / b) * output[1]),
            output[2]
        };
    }
}
```

You can test the implementation here: https://onlinegdb.com/volwDTwnl

Comment: Since OP seems to want to implement `modInverse` , its worth mentioning that if the gcd given by `output[2]` is 1 then `output[0]` is the inverse of `a` modulus `b`, otherwise there doesn't exist such inverse i.e. a, b are not coprime.